# Jenkins svn plugin clean removal

Tags: jenkins

After a simple apt-get update on ubuntu 10.11, I lost the svn polling possibility. None of my projects, that could poll svn, can anymore.
The plugin Update center shows an update is available for this plugin ( 1.34 -> 1.37 ) but update does not work, wether with web interface or cli.
Jenkins logs show a whole bunch of errors relating the subversion plugin

```
ATTENTION: Caught exception evaluating: it.isTagged(). Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.scm.SubversionTagAction.isTagged(SubversionTagAction.java:157)
[...]

25 janv. 2012 16:34:37 hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression evaluate
ATTENTION: Caught exception evaluating: it.isTagged(). Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException

[...]

INFO: Loaded all jobs
25 janv. 2012 16:34:06 hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter doUnmarshal
ATTENTION: Skipping a non-existent field list
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.NonExistentFieldException: No such field hudson.scm.SubversionTagAction.list
```

etc ... etc ...

I removed by hand :

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 jenkins nogroup     4096 2012-01-25 16:33 subversion
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins nogroup  2105983 2012-01-24 18:34 subversion.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins nogroup  2105983 2012-01-24 18:34 subversion.hpi
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins nogroup        0 2012-01-25 16:31 subversion.hpi.pinned
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins nogroup  2103308 2012-01-25 16:31 subversion.jpi
```

but the plugin keeps being listed in the update area.

Question : what is the proper procedure to remove EVERY and ALL references to this plugin, to make a very clean reinstall ? 
thanks

Comment: When you deleted the files, was the Jenkins daemon running? You have to make sure the Jenkins is completely stopped before you try to delete anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems to be common problem
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12449

try these steps

- Downgrade jenkins, restart
- Disable subversion plugin, restart
- Upgrade jenkins, restart
- Enable subversion plugin, restart
- Edit each build configuration, enable subversion, save.