# Jenkins not able to use SVN credentials or download new plugins/new versions

Tags: jenkins

**Can anyone suggest how to fix the two issues?**

**- Can't upgrade Jenkins and SVN plugin**

**- Can't connect to svn**

I am setting up Jenkins on a Windows 64 bit machine.  It's configured to run as a windows service.

We are running this on Windows 7 64 bit OS

Jenkins 1.482

I am able to do an SVN update/checkout from my user account on the machine.

When I attempt to set up a job on jenkins I get the following when trying to add svn credentials

```
FAILED: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: OPTIONS /svn/client/trunk failed
```

More details are:

```
FAILED: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: OPTIONS /svn/client/trunk failed

org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: OPTIONS /svn/client/trunk failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:298)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:283)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:271)
    at ...
```

I stopped the service and ran Jenkins from command line and tried the same thing - with the same result.

I am able to connect to the svn server with a tortoise client and via firefox with the same credentials.

In researching the issue I saw a few posts about similar problems and the only one that seems to claim to fix it is rolling back to Jenkins svn plugin version.

I then tried to install the latest jenkins and Plugin for svn.  The downloads failed.  Aha, I thought - obviously a firewall issue.  So I disable the firewall.

Still no good.  I can't automatically download or get the new Jenkins or SVN plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Try starting jenkins with this option:

```
-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols="SSLv3"
```

Or, if Jenkins is starting svn plugin in a separate JVM, try adding the line to wherever the svn plugin run configuration is.

It's a known problem with svnkit, which is used by Jenkins' svn plugin:

http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-176

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9247915/760757) answer can be helpful with regards to upgrading your svn plugin.

To change your Windows service commandline:

1. open a command line window **cmd.exe**
2. `sc qc "JenkinsSlave"` (if that's what your service name is)
3. select and copy the BINARY_PATH_NAME value
4. change it, adding `-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=""SSLv3""` after the jar path - mind the double quote
5. `sc config "JenkinsSlave" binPath= <paste the changed value copied earlier>`

Replace **JenkinsSlave** with your service name.

Comment: How do I set those parameters for running jenkins as a windows service?

Comment: unfortunately it does not seem to work.  And I can't upgrade jenkins automatically either

Comment: did you try [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9247915/760757) steps to resolve your upgrade issues?

Comment: I do not know how to "downgrade" jenkins.  I am able to disable svn plugin - but it is not clear how to downgrade, nor what version to downgrade to.

Comment: I guess Downgrade means uninstall your current, then install an older version, but I could be wrong as well. Maybe simply wiping it out will remedy the problem?

Comment: I am not sure which old version to use.  I tried an old one.  Still fails miserably.  Thanks for the help - I tried hudson as well and it fails.  I tried jenkins on 32 bit and it fails.  I have  really old version of hudson working fine so I am very confused about all these problems.

Comment: Can you edit your question, copy-pasting the `sc qc "JenkinsSlave"` command output?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 x64 has some automatic firewall settings.  You may need to open a firewall port to allow the connection.

You should be able to verify or eliminate this as a cause by trying to run your svn client outside Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

bit late topic, but did you try the following solution?

http://www.daangemist.nl/2014/03/03/jenkins-reports-sslv3-error-on-svn-update

that one worked out for me, in my case I wanted to use -Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols="TLSv1"

Comment: I am the one who wrote that post, good to see it helped you solve your problems.

Comment: The correct link seems to be http://www.daangemist.nl/2014/03/03/jenkins-reports-error-on-svn-update

Answer (score 0):

What about running Jenkins service with your account?

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  Does not work.  Neither does running jenkins from command line not as a service.