# svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: The element type “META” must be terminated by the matching end-tag “</META>”

Tags: svn, jenkins, hudson

I am getting some error like this, while checkout from svn in Jenkins. I deleted all the workspace and run the Jenkin job, then I run multiple times even same error.

Building in workspace /home/user/.jenkins/workspace/Buildprojectportal ERROR: Failed to update /svn/project/trunk/Development/projectroot org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: REPORT /svn/project/!svn/vcc/default failed at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:298) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:283) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:271) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:283) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:274) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getDatedRevision(DAVRepository.java:200) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicClient.java:477) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicClient.java:465) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.update(SVNUpdateClient.java:541) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:401) at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:136) at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:136) at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:788) at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:769) at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:753) at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:904) at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:877) at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:743) at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:685) at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1364) at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:670) at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88) at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:575) at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575) at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46) at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88) at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237) Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: REPORT /svn/project/!svn/vcc/default failed at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:146) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:89) ... 27 more Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: REPORT request failed on '/svn/project/!svn/vcc/default' svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: The element type "META" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "". (/svn/project/!svn/vcc/default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's problem with svnkit, which is used by Jenkins' svn plugin.

add option `-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=SSLv3`

look this answer: 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625614/jenkins-not-able-to-use-svn-credentials-or-download-new-plugins-new-versions)

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention, i am using Hudson,  how can i pass this parameter, there is two fields Repository URL and Local module directory.

Comment: It is a system property. Usually one sets it when starts JVM (java), i.e in the command script:

java -Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=SSLv3 -classpath a.jar:svnkit.jar:... mainClassName

Or one may set it programatically at runtime: 

System.setProperty("svnkit.http.sslProtocols", "SSLv3");